# Generating flex beans from Java ones and associated serialization code

Tags: java, apache-flex, web-services, serialization, adobe-indesign

I have a project that uses Java on the server part and Flex on the client one.

Both sides will (of course) share some common classes (like the beans used to describe my model). Those sides will communicate using different mechanisms :

- SOAP web-services (using JAX-WS on the server part) when talking through the network
- Serialization. Indeed, this project is to be deployed on InDesign (both Java and Flex code will be there). in that case, we have found a way to send events from the Flex code to the Java one, which requires serialization.

So, I'm looking for a way to not repeat myself, and write the beans on one side only (and let the other side be generated - by any mean, maven, FlashBuilder, you name it). Do you know such a solution ?

Comment: InDesign?? Anyway, you could try this http://sourceforge.net/projects/cleartoolkit/ Not posting as an answer because I haven't used it myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ClearToolkit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cleartoolkit/) which includes [DTO2Fx](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cleartoolkit/forums/forum/920865).

Another option is Gas3 from [Granite Data Services](http://www.graniteds.org/).

Comment: Yes.. I agree. I am using the whole Cleartoolkit eclipse plugin and its great capabilities to generate almost all your wiring includingservices, VO and DTO's with the hibernate configurations and spring integration are awesome. And it does make use of blazeds. All in all a great toolkit.

Comment: Will go on Granite Data Services, w<hich are integrated as default in flexmojos